# Chinese font size becomes bigger in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, font-size, cjk

I have a C# project, which supports many languages, including simplfied Chinese.
But in simplfied Chinese, in some PCs, the font size become bigger, so the UI looks weird.

In my windows 10, English PC, the font size is OK.

[image: font size is OK]

In my windows 7, Chinese laptop, (also in some Chinese PCs) the font size is bigger.
[image: font size is bigger]

How to fix this problem in C# project or in Windows language settings?

Really appreciate your help!

Have a nice day.

Eric Fang

Comment: Set as Font `Microsoft YaHei UI`, so you won't have a Font-fallback to different Fonts in different System versions.

Comment: As @Jimi said you should use a custom font to make a portable app, you can download it here(https://www.wfonts.com/font/microsoft-yahei) and you should bundle it with your app via an installer like `InstallSheild` or install the font in the target system manually

Comment: Really apreciate Jimi's and Peyman's replies. I will use the font Microsoft YaHei UI.